# Iterate Through an HTML Array With a Dropdown Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an arrary of values in an html page:
e.g.

```
    <td><input type="text"  id="ibillingCity[]" name="idbillingCity" value="Springfield"></input></td>
```

later on in the script tag I iterate through all the values using:

```
    $('input[id="ibillingCity[]"]').each(function() {
    $billingCity = $(this);
```

This works as expected and no issues with this

However when I try the same with a dropdown (select), it does not iterate through the values like a simple text field (i.e. like above)

```
    <select  id="ibillingState[]"   name="idbillingState"   class="compcol11">
      <option value="AB" >Alberta</option>
      <option value="BC" >Brittish Columbia</option>
    </select>
```

Shouldn't the $('input...').each(function) work the same as the first snippet (i.e. billingCity) as above?

Comment: What's the selector you're using. Do you want to iterate over the options, rather than the selects? like this `$('select[id="ibillingCity[]"] option').each`

Comment: FYI, IDs must be unique on document context, anyway, not clear what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
$('select[id="ibillingState[]"] option').each(function() {
    $billingCity = $(this);
```